# Two subrectangles $R,S$ are equal if and only if $\overset{°}R\cap S\neq\varnothing$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

What shown below is a reference from "Analysis on manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

[image]

So I want to prove that if $R=R_1\times...\times R_n$ and $S=S_1\times...\times S_n$ are two rectangles of $P$ then $R=S$ if and only if $\overset{°}R\cap S\neq\varnothing$.

Clearly if $R=S$ the statement is trivially true. So now we prove that if $R\neq S$ then $\overset{°}R\cap S=\varnothing$. Previously we observe that if $U_i$ and $V_i$ are two different subrectangles of the $i$-th subpartition of $P$ for some $i=1,...,k$ then $\overset{°}U_i\cap V_i=\varnothing$, because the subrectangles of $P_i$ are defined as the compact intervals whose ends are adjacent points of the subpartition $P_i$. So if $R\neq S$ then there exist $i=1,...,k$ such that $R_i=\pi_i[R]\neq\pi_i[S]=S_i$ and so it follows that 
$$
\overset{°}R\cap S=\Big(\overset{°}R_1\times...\times \overset{°}R_i\times...\times\overset{°}R_n\Big)\cap\Big(S_1\times...\times S_i\times...\times S_n\Big)=\Big(\overset{°}R_1\cap S_1\Big)\times...\times\Big(\overset{°}R_i\cap S_i\Big)\times...\times\Big(\overset{°}R_n\cap S_n\Big)=\Big(\overset{°}R_1\cap S_1\Big)\times...\times\Big(\varnothing\Big)\times...\times\Big(\overset{°}R_n\cap S_n\Big)=\varnothing
$$
and so the statement follows immediately

So I ask if my proof is correct and if not then I ask to prove if the statement if true or false. Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That argument works. Alternatively, you could note that if $R\ne S$, then there are a $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and an $a\in P_k$ such that either

- $R\subseteq\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n:x_k\le a\}$ and $S\subseteq\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n:x_k\ge a\}$, or
- $S\subseteq\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n:x_k\le a\}$ and $R\subseteq\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n:x_k\ge a\}$.

Without loss of generality assume the former; then

$$\operatorname{int}R\subseteq\{\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n:x_k<a\}\subseteq\Bbb R^n\setminus S\;.$$